# Very very light selector engine

Tags: javascript, dom

I want a selector engine, with not many features, that is very very small.

I only need to identify by tag, id, and class - and be able to nest those things...

```
// select info paragraph within content area
#content p.info

// change headings above size h3
h1, h2, h3
```

I don't need to check if the tag as an attribute which matches a regex pattern or anything like that. I want only to use fast selection methods, on well formed HTML.

I can only find full featured libraries online, which all weigh in around 3K - which I feel is far too much for a small job.

Comment: 3k is too large? are you from 1995?

Comment: getElementById, getElementsByClassName, getElementsByTagName

Comment: The `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` functions are supported everywhere except IE7 and below. They're even better supported than `getElementsByClassName()` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see what is wrong with native javascript?

```
document.getByElementId(...);
document.getElementsByClassName(...);
document.getElementsByTagName(...);
```

Or even this (can be used in all modern browsers [including IE8+]):

```
document.querySelectorAll(...);
document.querySelector(...);
```

Comment: not to mention document.querySelector in modern browsers

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `getElementsByClassName()`, and thanks to the fact that IE9 doesn't run on Windows XP that makes it sadly relevant.

Comment: With those methods, how can I select paragraphs inside a div with class content for example? (like: `div.content p`)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("div.content p")`

Comment: ***Lets not forget to mention*** aside from getElementById all of these are `context.func()` which means you can chain element.getElementsByX to control specificity. Also querySelector() is a live element querySelectorAll is a static node list.

Comment: How can you `chain element.getElementsByX to control specificity`? Have you a link to a tutorial or documentation?

Comment: @rlemon ^^^^ see OPs comment above.

Comment: if you want #someID > p you can do document.getElementById('someID').getElementsByTagName('p'); now there are obvious limitations, just remember these are nodeLists not arrays... and you should be able to manage them